# Problem when rename files and change layout

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a PC running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, unity 7.2.6, and two keyboard layouts - English (US) and Russian. I am using the Layout change keys combination - <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

When I am renaming files in Nautilus and changing layout, the renaming of file is interrupted, as though I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> (The cursor disappears). Please help with this problem.

Comment: Can you not just change the layout before attempting to rename?

Comment: Try clicking on the keyboard layout indicator in the top panel

Comment: I think this behaviour is by design. Probably there is no way to change that as user. You could file a feature request against Nautilus maybe if this is so important for you, but I'd simply suggest to select the appropriate layout before starting to rename.

Comment: Sometimes i need to use two layouts in one file name.

Comment: Guys, do you have this behaviour too?